# Define an Reference variable in VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I want to fetch the user IP address and save it into the database but I can't reference them.
this is the script that I'm using

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
             setRating(){
               fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    var ip = data.ip;
                    console.log(data.ip);
                });
                var pathArray = location.pathname.split('/');
                var uid = pathArray[2];
                fetch('/api/rating/new',{
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify({business:1, **user:3**, rating:this.rating}),
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    swal.fire(
                        'The Business Rated!',
                        'Done.',
                        'success'
                        )
                }).catch(err => {
                    swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Oops...',
                        text: 'Request Faild',
                    })
                });
            },

        },
        mounted() {
            this.getRating();
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        }
    }
</script>
```

I fetch the IP address and get the correct response in consol but when I reference it to the **user** 
it didn't work

this is the way I referenced

```
body: JSON.stringify({business:1, **user:ip**, rating:this.rating}),
```

this is the error:

> "ReferenceError: IP is not defined"

and when I put **this.ip** it response NULL in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite a code using `async/await` to properly accessing the variable `ip`.

**OR** define `var ip = null` at the begging of `setRating` and then just assign a value to it `ip = data.ip;`.

I recommend you to use the first way as it looks clearer and sequential and easy to read.